# Close Button doesn't appear in Glade

Tags: c, gtk3, glade

I am creating a simple interface in Glade 3.22.2 and it shows everything as desired except the X button/close button even though 'Deletable' flag is checked in Glade. Using Ubuntu on WSL2 and gtk+ 3.20.
When I run glade from my terminal I get these:

```
GladeUI-Message: 07:40:46.311: 1 missing displayable value for GtkWidget::events
GladeUI-Message: 07:40:46.311: 3 missing displayable value for GtkWidget::AtkObject::accessible-role
GladeUI-Message: 07:40:46.367: 1 missing displayable value for GtkEntry::input-purpose
GladeUI-Message: 07:40:46.367: 2 missing displayable value for GtkEntry::input-hints
GladeUI-Message: 07:40:46.461: No displayable values for property GtkMenu::anchor-hints
GladeUI-Message: 07:40:46.495: 5 missing displayable value for GtkAboutDialog::license-type
GladeUI-Message: 07:40:46.566: 1 missing displayable value for GtkCellRendererAccel::accel-mode
GladeUI-Message: 07:40:46.616: No displayable values for property WebKitWebView::automation-presentation-type
GladeUI-Message: 07:40:46.616: No displayable values for property WebKitWebView::camera-capture-state
GladeUI-Message: 07:40:46.616: No displayable values for property WebKitWebView::microphone-capture-state
GladeUI-Message: 07:40:46.616: No displayable values for property WebKitWebView::display-capture-state
GladeUI-Message: 07:40:46.622: No displayable values for property WebKitSettings::hardware-acceleration-policy
GladeUI-Message: 07:40:46.622: Glade needs artwork; a default icon will be used for the following classes:
    GThemedIcon     needs an icon named 'widget-gtk-themedicon'
    WebKitWebView   needs an icon named 'widget-webkit2gtk-webview'
    WebKitSettings  needs an icon named 'widget-webkit2gtk-settings'
    GtkApplicationWindow    needs an icon named 'widget-gtk-applicationwindow'

(glade:370): Gtk-WARNING **: 07:40:53.398: Error loading theme icon 'dialog-warning' for stock: Icon 'dialog-warning' not present in theme Yaru
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: I don't do much with Gtk+3, I can't stand it personally, but from your errors, the `"needs an icon named"` problem is clear. The underlying problem is between Gtk+2 and Gtk+3 the GDK icon handling was changed. This remained a moving target throughout Gtk+3 development, ultimately ending with a gnome library `libadwaita` being made a dependency of the toolkit (or what was left of it). Check where those named icons come from. The solution might be a simple as linking with the needed library.

Comment: I tried to upgrade. Latest was 3.40.0 but when I followed the steps in the README I could only install 3.22.2.
Above warnings persist. Close button still not showing

Comment: It is a moving target issue. See [Glade loading issues - Solved](https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/glade-loading-issues.82942/) and Bug [3.38.2 closes when trying to create a Gtk.Dialog](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/glade/-/issues/536). This is the difficultly with doing anything with Gtk+3. Unless you rearrange your code for every minor-version, you run into just this kind of issue. Gnome swears this will be fixed soon in Gtk4 -- but coders have left Gtk like lemmings over a cliff due to the libadwaita dependency. Basically Gtk is reduced to supporting Gnome only.

Comment: So what do you suggest I do? Write XML by hand?

Comment: With Gtk+2, I always stayed away from glade and just coded it directly.  Very early glade was good at generating Gtk+2 C-source code. Once Gtk+3 came on seen coding was pushed into using the "buildables" XML scripting, you added another degree of separation between the programmer and his code. Now, what happened "automagically" behind the scene was suppose to free the programmer from having to code menus, toolbars, context-menus, etc.. That's great when it all works, but...  Now look at [Gtk+3 Reference](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/glade/-/issues/536) under `IconFactory` - best bet.